# How to feed data from .sigmf-data file to a CNN classifier

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, complex-numbers

I am trying to build a CNN classifier, which takes in demodulated IQ samples as input.

The CNN architecture is as follows:

- It consists of 4 layers, with 2 convolution layers and 2 fully connected layers.
- The input to the CNN is a windowed sequence of demodulated IQ samples (we also introduce Gaussian noise of power less than -13dB)
- Each complex value is represented as 2 real values (real and imaginary part), and the length of the input is 128. Hence dimension of the input data is $2*128$. This is then fed to the convolution layer.
- First convolution layer consists of 50 filters, each of size 1*7.
- Second convolution layer consists of 50 filters, each of size 2*7.
- Each convolution layer is followed by a Rectified Linear Unit.
- The output of the second convolution layer is then provided as input to the first fully connected layer, which has 256 neurons.
- Second fully connected layer has 80 neurons.
- A softmax classifier is used in the last layer to output the probability of each sample being fed to the CNN.
- Dropout rate is 50% at the dense layer.
- Regularization parameter is 0.0001.
- Adam optimizer is used with learning rate=0.0001.
- cross-entropy is used as the loss function.
- Everything is implemented in Keras running on top of TensorFlow.

The demodulated IQ samples are stored in 16 files in `.sigmf-data` format.

I can load data from these files separately by:

```py
signal = sigmffile.fromfile("Demod_WiFi_cable_X310_3123D76_IQ#1_run1.sigmf-data")
samples = temp_signal.read_samples()
```

This is the full code:

```py
from sigmf import SigMFFile, sigmffile
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import regularizers
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# loading data from one .sigmf-datafile
signal = sigmffile.fromfile("Demod_WiFi_cable_X310_3123D76_IQ#1_run1.sigmf-data")
samples = temp_signal.read_samples()

# defining model
model=keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(filters=50,kernel_size=(7,1),activation='relu',input_shape=(1,128,2,1)),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=50,kernel_size=(7,2),activation='relu'),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
    layers.Dense(units=256,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)),
    layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
    layers.Dense(units=80,activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)),
    layers.Dense(units=16,activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I don't know how to feed data to the CNN as it is entirely different case when we feed data in image form.

Comment: Did you check n-west's [notebook](https://github.com/n-west/Wideband-RF-Signal-Detection-with-Machine-Learning/blob/main/3_Spectral_Segmentation.ipynb)?